# The Function is running without even calling in the code , can you update it for me , no errors shown in terminal

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the Code
I am trying to make my own Python List Generator
You can use this for your personal use too , if you want
When i run the code the output is lbl2 shows []
and the theme ubuntu that i Typed is not working
same no errors in terminal

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as TkFont
import tkinter
from ttkthemes import themed_tk as tk
import random

root = tk.ThemedTk()
root.get_themes()
root.set_theme("ubuntu")
root.title("            List Generator")
root.geometry("300x300")
root.resizable(0 , 0)

Head = Label (root , text = "List Generator for Pyhton" , font=("Arial Bold" , 15))
Head.pack(anchor = CENTER )

lbl1 = Label (root , text = '''Type Words to make a List 
Use space to seprate Words in List''' )
lbl1.pack(anchor = CENTER)


ListBox = Entry( root  , width = 40)
ListBox.place( x = 26 , y = 100)

lbl2 = Label( root ,  text= "")
lbl2.place( x = 26 , y = 175)

#Done = ListBox.get()
#Output = Done.split()

def Donn():
    Done = ListBox.get()
    Output = Done.split()
    lbl2.config(text = str(Output) )


Btn_Done = Button( root , text = "Convert" , command = Donn() )
Btn_Done.place(x = 117 , y = 125 )


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
Btn_Done = Button( root , text = "Convert" , command = Donn() )
```

The parameter to `command` needs to be a function, but you are not passing a function.  You are CALLING the function and passing what it returns, which is `None`.  To fix it, pass the function itself:

```
Btn_Done = Button( root , text = "Convert" , command = Donn )
```

Comment: But what about the ubantu theame any ideas about it?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.